# На пк при подключении кабеля от роутера скорость 10мбит, на ноуте 100мбит

Tags: windows-10, router

Может кто подсказать, возможно ли что в  пк антивирус или какая то служба включать сама ограничитель скорость , на пк скорость при подключении кабеля от роутера скорость 10мбит, на ноуте 100мбит

Пробовал сбросить сетевые драйверы, в настройках дуплекс также ставил 100мбит или автосогласование. И тд

Предложите ваши варианты

Comment: Провод проверяли? Может там несколько жил перебито